# GAS - Using Map to check an array against another array

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to check every individual value in array 'chkArr' to check if that string occurs in another array 'arr' and if it does return blank "".  I have it working for the first value "text" but it isn't looping though the other element of chkArr the way I expected.

If I manually change the loop variable 'rep' I get the correct result for whichever array element is selected.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  Perhaps I need to move the loop out of the filterLogic function?

```
function myFunction() {
  var arr = [["random.text1"],[6.0],["othermsg"],[8],["testtext2"]];
  var newArr = arr.map(filterLogic);
  Logger.log(newArr);

}

var filterLogic = function(item){
var chkArr = [["text"],[6.0],["other"]["other"]];
    
    for (var rep = 0; rep < chkArr.length; rep++) {
      if(item.toString().indexOf(chkArr[rep]) === -1){return item;} else {return [""];}
    }
}
```

So the result I would hope to get from the above would be:

```
[[], [], [], [8.0], []]
```

However what I actually get is:

```
[[], [6.0], [othermsg], [8.0], []]
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it which does give me the result I need.  I'm sure there is a better way still to do this so if anyone has a neater method please share.

My solution.

```
function myFunction() {
  var arr = [["random.text1"],[6.0],["othermsg"],[8],["testtext2"]];
  rep = 0;
  for (rep = 0; rep <= 2; rep++){
  var newArr = arr.map(filterLogic);
     
  Logger.log(newArr);
  }
}

var filterLogic = function(item){
   var chkArr = [["text"],[6],["other"]];
   
      if(item.toString().indexOf(chkArr[rep]) === -1){return item;} else {return [""];}
    }
```